# Metodo POST no funciona con POSTMAN en LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, api, postman

Tengo una API en LARAVEL el metodo get funciona a la perfeccion con POSTMAN, pero el metodo POST  me da el siguiente resultado:

Peticion Postman:

http://localhost:8000/persona?nombre=rtret&apellido=tterterte

Rutas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que me lanza POSTMAN es:

> PAGE EXPIRED

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Page Expired</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #636b6f;
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 100;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .full-height {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .flex-center {
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .position-ref {
            position: relative;
        }

        .code {
            border-right: 2px solid;
            font-size: 26px;
            padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .message {
            font-size: 18px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <div class="code">
            419 </div>

        <div class="message" style="padding: 10px;">
            Page Expired </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sospecho que es por el CRSF, porque uso esa ruta (POST) por medio de un formulario html y guarda correctamente los datos.

Comment: Como tus rutas están en `web.php`, tendrías que agregar un input con el CSRF token a las solicitudes post https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-introduction . Para una api, usualmente las rutas van en `api.php`, que no utilizan el middleware `web` donde se guarda la sesión.

Comment: Puse las rutas en api.php y POSTMAN me devuelve que la ruta no existe.

Comment: Las rutas de api llevan un prefix [http://localhost:8000/api/persona?nombre=rtret&apellido=tterterte](http://localhost:8000/api/persona?nombre=rtret&apellido=tterterte), mira de nuevo el listado de rutas y verás cuál es la uri.